# Joomla 3: How to get IDs of articles in specific category

Tags: module, joomla3.0

I am writing a small module for Joomla 3+.
The module should randomly display several articles from a specific category.
The category will be specified in the module parameters.

How can I query for articles from a category I specify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the query below and adjust for your needs:

```
    public function getMyArticles($catid){
        $result = null;
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('id, title, alias') // add other fields that might interest you
                ->from('#__content')
                ->where('catid='.$db->quote($catid))
                ->order('RAND() LIMIT 4'); // just an example for the ordering clause
        try {
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $result = $db->loadObjectList();
        }
        catch(RuntimeException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Hope it helps ;)